# Google Play Service FATAL ERROR

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

In my project I use GCM for push notification from server.

I foollow instruction https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup to add Google Play Service in my project.

And everything work fine on my device (Galaxy NOTE S3), but when I start testing on another emulators (include genymotion) I got FATAL ERROR:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.zza.zzaR(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzn.zziJ(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzz.zza(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzaa.zzDj(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzw.zzaT(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1058)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4560)
at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4190)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4132)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I check availability by method:

```
public static boolean checkPlayServices(Activity activity) {

    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

And call this method in onResume of MainActitvity.class:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    if(SMSSenderHelper.checkPlayServices(this)){
        startService(new Intent(this, RegistrationIntentService.class));
    }else{
        finish();
    }
}
```

**SOLUTION (in my case):**

1. review your build.gradle
2. change Application class:

   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
       super.attachBaseContext(base);
       MultiDex.install(this);
   }

Comment: Have you install Google Play Service on your emulator yet?

Comment: Not have, but in that way application should show error dialog, not FATAL ERROR

Comment: I'm think that's because GcmListenerService, but how fix it

Comment: Could you post your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: have you added library ??

Comment: I did not add library, only change build.gradle and sync

Answer (score 0):

Did you see any `Google` related apps (Ex: Google Play Store, Gmail...) in your emulator? If not, your emulator does not include `Google service`, so the `Exception` will be occured. Try to install [Gapps for your genymotion](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-install-google-services-on-genymotion/en) and try again.

Edit:
Have you added Google Play Services library like [Google guidline](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)?
Note from Google guidline (emulator 4.2.2 and above):

> To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use
> either:
>
> A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and
> includes Google Play Store.
>
> The Android emulator with an AVD that runs
> the Google APIs platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

Comment: Yes, i follow google manual, and add line 
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
and sync

Comment: Did you add this to the bottom of that file?  
`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: app not even reached that line in onResume

Comment: @mkoval Change your emulator with 4.2.2 or above and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

This is some line of code you have to define in Manifest file if you want to use GCMListenerService:

```
<receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="training.com.chatgcmapplication" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="training.com.services.MessageListenerService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```